# Keeping child form centered in MDI parent

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I've created a main form that is an MDI form, and also a child form.

How I can make the child form remain centered in the parent MDI form whenever I "maximize" or "restore" the MDI form?

Comment: If its maximized or minimized, how would you centre it?

Comment: @NhemAranas Hi, I have edited your question to clarify what the problem is. Feel free to rollback changes or re-edit if I put anything in there that's not what you meant.

Answer (score 3):

Let me see if I understand you right, you want your MDI application to open your child form in the center of the Form, then keep it there no matter what you do to resize it.  The Mdi interface has its own ideas on how to place forms, the first step is to have the Child form set its position in its load event, then you can keep it in the center by using the Parents Resize event. This is a sample using 2 Forms, see if it is what you are looking for.

**Form1** *Mdi Parent*

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.MdiParent = this;
        frm2.Show();
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        CenterForms();
        base.OnResize(e);
    }
    private void CenterForms()
    {
        foreach (var form in MdiChildren) //This will center all of the Child Forms
        {
            form.Left = (ClientRectangle.Width - form.Width) / 2;
            form.Top = (ClientRectangle.Height - form.Height) / 2;
        }

    }
}
```

**Form2** *Mdi Child*

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Left = (MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Width - Width) / 2;
        Top = (MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Height - Height)/2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the child form starting position in center of Parent Like This

your Child Form

```
this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the child form property "StartPosition" to CenterParent

OR

When you are loading new form, add this code

```
Form frm = new Form();
frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
frm.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + (this.Width - frm.Width) / 2, this.Location.Y + (this.Height - frm.Height) / 2);
frm.Show(this);
```